# What should I do to show the previous data when I'm updating some information on website in Django?

Tags: html, django, forms

Here, on my site admin can update product information. Hereafter clicking that green update button a form will appear. but I want that as admin is updating information, previous information will also appear in this form. So, I want to show previous data already filled up in this form. How can I do this as I'm not using any **ModelForm** here

[image: Sample Image]

**views.py**

```
def update_product(request,product_id):

    if request.method=='POST':
            product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)

            product.product_name = request.POST['product_name']
            product.category = request.POST['product_category']
            product.price = request.POST['product_price']
            product.image = request.FILES['product_photo']
            product.description = request.POST['product_description']
            product.pub_date = datetime.today()
            product.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Product has been updated successfully!!!')
            return redirect("/") 

    else:
        return HttpResponse("404-Not Found")
```

form is inside a modal in **fruit.html**:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#updateModal"><i class="bi bi-arrow-repeat"></i></button>

                          <div class="modal fade" id="updateModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="updateModalLabel"
                          aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog">
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="updateModalLabel">Add New Products</h5>
                                      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                          aria-label="Close"></button>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-body">
      
      
                                      <form action="{% url 'update_product' i.product_id %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                          {% csrf_token %}
      
                                          <div class="mb-3">
                                              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Product Name:</label>
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name" name="product_name"
                                                  placeholder="E.g. Potato Regular" required />
                                          </div>
      
                                          <div class="mb-3">
                                              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Product
                                                  Category:</label>
                                              <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" id="product_category" name="product_category" required>
                                                  <option selected>Choose Category</option>
                                                  <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
                                                  <option value="Vegetable">Vegetable</option>
                                                  <option value="Toy">Toy</option>
                                                  <option value="Medicine">Medicine</option>
                                                  <option value="Stationery">Stationery</option>
                                                  <option value="Pet">Pet</option>
                                                  <option value="Electric">Electric</option>
                                                  <option value="Meat">Meat</option>
                                                  <option value="Fish">Fish</option>
                                              </select>
                                          </div>
      
                                          <div class="mb-3">
                                              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Product Price:</label>
                                              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="product_price" name="product_price"
                                                  placeholder="E.g. 100" required />
                                          </div>
      
                                          <div class="mb-3">
                                              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Product Photo:</label> <br>
                                              <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control" id="product_photo" name="product_photo" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload" required>
                                            </div>
      
                                          <div class="mb-3">
                                              <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Description</label>
                                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_description" name="product_description" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" aria-label="Upload" required>
                                          </div>
      
                                          <div class="modal-footer">
                                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                                  data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
                                          </div>
                                      </form>
      
      
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, here is my answer.
In your **views.py** get product with id

```
def update_product(request,product_id):

    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id) #new

    if request.method=='POST':
            product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)

            product.product_name = request.POST['product_name']
            product.category = request.POST['product_category']
            product.price = request.POST['product_price']
            product.image = request.FILES['product_photo']
            product.description = request.POST['product_description']
            product.pub_date = datetime.today()
            product.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Product has been updated successfully!!!')
            return redirect("/") 
    return render(temp.html, {'product': product})
```

In your **fruit.html** add product info to inputs value.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="product_price" value="{{product.price}}" name="product_price" placeholder="E.g. 100" required />
```

Comment: Yes you understood But unfortunately not worked for me.  Is it because here in your code after **return redirect("/")** this will never reach **return (temp.html, {'product': product})**  @mirodil

Comment: **return render(temp.html, {'product': product})** runs before **return redirect("/")** which is Post request